# Flask Import Error: cannot import name 'app' from 'application'

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-restful

I have my directory as:

```
-- application 
 |- __init__.py
run.py
```

i have code in `__init__.py` as:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
```

run.py as:

```
from application import app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

error shown:

```
from application import app
ImportError: cannot import name 'app' from 'application'
```

Comment: How do you run your program?

Comment: running this on termina python run.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code suddenly works all of a sudden, i don't know how. so closing this question

Answer (score 0):

Other than `from flask import flask` needing to be `from flask import Flask`, seems like that should work. Might be a stupid question, but have you saved all the files?

Comment: I indeed have from flask import Flask. It's just a typo there